# Globally setting a JUnit runner instead of @RunWith

Tags: junit, junit-runner

Without looking into JUnit source itself (my next step) is there an easy way to set the default Runner to be used with every test without having to set @RunWith on every test?  We've got a huge pile of unit tests, and I want to be able to add some support across the board without having to change every file.

Ideally I'm hope for something like: -Djunit.runner="com.example.foo".

Comment: So I peeked into the code where the RunWith annotation is processed and I didn't see anything where it would pull the default runner from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to define globally, but if writing you own main function is an option, you can do something similar through code. You can create a custom `RunnerBuilder` and pass it to a `Suite` together with your test classes.

```java
Class<?>[] testClasses = { TestFoo.class, TestBar.class, ... };
RunnerBuilder runnerBuilder = new RunnerBuilder() {
    @Override
    public Runner runnerForClass(Class<?> testClass) throws Throwable {
        return new MyCustomRunner(testClass);
    }
};
new JUnitCore().run(new Suite(runnerBuilder, testClasses));
```

This won't integrate with UI test runners like the one in Eclipse, but for some automated testing scenarios it could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit doesn’t supporting setting the runner globally. You can hide away the @RunWith in a base class, but this probably won't help in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might be able to influence the test behavior globally by using a custom `RunListener`. Here is how to configure it with the Maven Surefire plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_custom_listeners_and_reporters