# How to specify JUnit custom runner for Surefire Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

Suppose I have a `junit` custom class loader, which reads the test data from a text file and create and run tests in runtime. The runner uses no test class.

Now I would like to run it with `surefire` maven plugin. That is, I would like to specify the runner as a parameter of the the `surefire` plugin "execution" in the `pom.xml`.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** As far as I know, there is no way of specifying a `Runner` class in the maven-surefire-plugin. However, you should be able to create a single Test-Class and use the `@RunWith(YourRunner.class)` to let it run with your custom runner.

I think that is because the intended use case for `Runner`s is on a **per-test basis**, not on a project-level. You can have a project with mixed uses of various Runners, e.g. some are Spring-based, some are concurrent, some run with JUnit3, some with JUnit4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might be able to influence the test behavior globally by using a custom `RunListener`. Here is how to configure it with the Maven Surefire plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_custom_listeners_and_reporters

(I posted the same response to a similar question, namely: [Globally setting a JUnit runner instead of @RunWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886085/globally-setting-a-junit-runner-instead-of-runwith/8532345#8532345))

Answer (score 0):

In my project i resolve same task with plugin [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

I have custom Runner, which run junit test with special parameters. I execute my runner with maven command: mvn test -Dparam1=value1 -Dparam2=value2 -Dparam3=value3

In pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                        <mainClass>com.example.domain.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```